# Registering ASP.NET in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to deploy the website I built on Visual Studio. I would like to host on IIS instead of the default ASP.NET Development Server so that I can access the website on my phone.

One of the steps I need to do is register ASP.NET on IIS. I run the following in the command prompt:

1)C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

2)aspnet_regiis -i

However, I get this error message:
*This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.*

Here are the details of my system:
ASP.NET 4.0
Visual Studio 2010
IIS 10
Windows 10

I have been to the link provided and it is not helpful at all.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem or is there another way for me to host on IIS instead of ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says in the message - go into "turn windows features on/off" in control panel?

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10, you can "setup" IIS and asp.net using the **Program and Features**...

Go to **control panel** | **Program and Features** | **Turn Windows features on or off**

Inside there locate the "**Internet Information Services**"

There ensure that "World Wide Web Services" is checked (partial) and inside "**application development features**" the **.Net Extensible** and **asp.net** are checked !

[image]
<sub>(source: [planethost.gr](http://www.planethost.gr/so/OpenIssAspNetWin10.gif))</sub>